# Python 3.3 for linux terminal shell

Tags: python, linux, terminal, ubuntu-12.04

I've recently installed linux and got it working as a dual boot on my laptop. I have both python 2.7 and python 3.3 installed on my system. 
The problem is that when I run `python` it runs the python 2.7 interpreter rather than python 3.3 as I would like it to. I can run the 3.3 interpreter with `python3.3` but I would rather run the latest version with the shorter command, however I don't know how to change this. Any help regarding this would be most appreciated.

Comment: That might not be a good idea because it could break a lot of other scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to change what `python` gets you, one of the safer ways to get `python3.3` is to use an alias described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229416/making-python-3-3-default-python-3-interpreter-instead-of-3-2#229491).  You may want to alias `python` to `python3` as that should give you 3.3 now, and 3.4 when you upgrade in the future.

If you want to update the default systemwide, you can try:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

as mentioned [elsewhere](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14615/how-do-i-make-the-terminal-run-python-3-1/14624#14624).

Edit: Please note that various operating systems integrate a specific version of python and various updates and packages may break if `python` doesn't work exactly as expected.  There are, of course, many ways to handle python versions (use of `python3` on the command line, virtualenv, pythonbrew, to name some of them).

Comment: I don't think I did everything correctly but I did eventually get the system to recognise `python` as `python3.3` though I'm buggered if I know how :P